# Como estruturar pastas e arquivos React Js?

Tags: react, react-router, react-dom

Estou começando aprender React Js e estou com a intenção de criar um site nele, porém fiquei com uma dúvida.

O `React Js` é a **base de componentes**, certo?

Eu tenho o `App.js` onde eu chamo os meus **componentes** e ele irá mostrar na tela.

Vamos supor que quero começar a fazer a **Index do meu site**.
Dentro da pasta `src` eu crio uma pasta chamada `componentes`.

Dentro da pasta `componentes`, crio `umarquivo.js` e `umarquivo.css` respectivamente para colocar o css do `arquivo.js`

Pensando pelo lado de criar componentes, eu não farei igual faço uma página normal com bootstrap apenas criando index.php.

Eu teria que fazer os componentes, não é?

Exemplo:
**pasta:** `src/componentes/header.js`
**pasta:** `src/componentes/header.css`

No `header.js` eu criaria a `header` do meu site, e no `header.css` eu criaria o `css` da minha `header`, certo?

A minha pergunta seria essa... Como eu faço para organizar os componentes?
Para cada `"página"` eu criaria uma **pasta** dentro de `src/componentes/index`
E nessa **pasta index**, eu criaria os `componentes` da mesma?
Suponhamos que eu queira então criar a página `"contato"`, eu criaria `src/componentes/contato`
E dentro da pasta contato, os componentes `.js` e `.css`?

Pois penso que se eu não separar por pastas, os arquivos ficarão confusos quando o site estiver finalizado, pensando, é claro, que o site seria grande.

**Me aprofundando mais na pergunta, o meu questionamento é: Como estruturar as `pastas` e os arquivos `.js` e `.css` para que estejam organizados e fáceis de serem encontrados, principalmente para manutenção?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particularmente eu gosto de utilizar a estrutura abaixo.
Separo `components` (componentes realmente reutilizáveis em qualquer ponto da aplicação), `pages` (as páginas), `services` (qualquer acesso externo), `helpers` (funções para formatação de data, números, etc).

Dentro de cada pasta de componente, deixo o index.js e o styles.css do arquivo em questão:

```
root
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── Header
│   │   ├── ├── index.js
│   │   ├── ├── styles.css
│   │   ├── Card
│   │   ├── ├── index.js
│   │   ├── ├── styles.css
...
...
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── Register
│   │   ├── ├── index.js
│   │   ├── ├── styles.css
│   │   ├── Profile
│   │   ├── ├── index.js
│   │   ├── ├── styles.css
...
...
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── api.js
│   │   ├── ibge.js
...
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── masks.js
│   │   ├── dateFormatter.js
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> O React Js é a base de componentes, certo?

Sim, segundo o próprio site: [Baseado em componentes - Crie componentes encapsulados que gerenciam seu próprio estado e então, combine-os para criar UIs complexas.](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/)

> No header.js eu criaria a header do meu site, e no header.css eu criaria o css da minha header, certo?
>
> ---
>
> A minha pergunta seria essa... Como eu faço para organizar os componentes? Para cada "página" eu criaria uma pasta dentro de src/componentes/index E nessa pasta index, eu criaria os componentes da mesma? Suponhamos que eu queira então criar a página "contato", eu criaria src/componentes/contato E dentro da pasta contato, os componentes .js e .css?

A organização dos componentes é meio que pessoal, não tem um padrão totalmente estabelecido, mas, vou propor a você algo que a maioria no momento faz que é o seguinte.

Crie uma pasta dentro do `src` com o nome de `components` ai vamos super que vai ter que criar um top da sua página, então, faz o seguinte dentro de `components` cria uma pasta `Header` (`components\Header` e observer que o `H` é maiúsculo isso é um padrão utilizado quando for componente) e dentro dessa pasta um arquivo `index.js` e para o seu css especifico `index.css` e assim por diante.

```
src
    /components
               /Header
               /Body
               /Footer
```

isso seria a parte do componentes de uma aplicação. Se você tiver um `css` global ou você importa dentro do componente Pai ou coloque na pasta `public` dentro do `index.html`

> Pois penso que se eu não separar por pastas, os arquivos ficarão
> confusos quando o site estiver finalizado, pensando, é claro, que o
> site seria grande.

Sim a forma de separar por componentes e organizar de uma maneira lógica em pastas vai auxiliar a parte da manutenção e como relatado anteriormente essa organização é um das mais utilizadas.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso acredito que você deveria estudar design patterns, já que entender isso é exatamente o que sua dúvida busca.

Recomendo você dá uma olhada no modelo Fractal - Uma estrutura de aplicativos React para escala infinita.

(Fractal — A react app structure for infinite scale)

Você pode ler sobre no artigo abaixo. Se não souber inglês, use o google translate.

https://hackernoon.com/fractal-a-react-app-structure-for-infinite-scale-4dab943092af